# Qt: QSS and drawComplexControl()

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I have a QDialog containing a QTableView, along with a custom delegate showing a QComboBox for enum types.
When the row is not selected, I still want the QComboBox to be visible (I would like to avoid using QTableView::openPersistentEditor()).
To do so, the custom delegate forwards the paint event to the following method:

```
QStyleOptionViewItem &option) const
{
    painter->save();

    QStyleOptionComboBox comboBoxOption;
    comboBoxOption.rect = option.rect;
    comboBoxOption.state = option.state;
    comboBoxOption.state |= QStyle::State_Enabled;
    comboBoxOption.editable = false;
    comboBoxOption.currentText = enumInfo.valueToKey(curValue);

    // The cast is successful, and srcWidget is the QTableView
    QWidget *srcWidget = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(option.styleObject);

    // style->metaObject()->className() = QStyleSheetStyle
    QStyle *style = srcWidget ? srcWidget->style() : QApplication::style();

    // However, the QSS is ignored here (while srcWidget->styleSheet() correctly
    // returns the style I've set in Qt Designer)
    style->drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &comboBoxOption, painter, srcWidget);
    style->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ComboBoxLabel, &comboBoxOption, painter, srcWidget);

    painter->restore();
}
```

The problem is that I’ve styled the combo box control using QSS, but drawComplexControl() seems to ignore that, despite using the QTableView’s style. Here’s a screenshot:

[image: Application screenshot]

Is it possible for drawComplexControl() to consider the style sheet?

Thanks

Comment: Ok, I found the solution: `drawComplexControl()` works as expected only if we call it from the `QStyleSheetStyle` subclass (casting is not needed) AND we pass an instance of the widget with that style applied (in my question `srcWidget` points to a `QTableView`, which is **wrong**. I need instead a `QComboBox` instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the only way is to grab widget with QPixmap::grabWidget(). And to use this image in delegate.
Seems, that it is not possible to do because of [QSS limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138100/how-to-draw-control-with-qstyle-and-with-specified-qss)

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid of that conclusion. 
The weird thing is that the `style` variable is actually a `QStyleSheetStyle` (a private Qt class), which is responsible to draw widgets according to the style sheet (and actually it does, with normal widgets!). 
From here [Qt Docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html):

_When a style sheet is active, the QStyle returned by `QWidget::style()` is a wrapper "style sheet" style, not the platform-specific style. The wrapper style ensures that any active style sheet is respected (omissis)_

I hope this will get fixed sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to use dirty hacks with casting style() to private QStyleSheetStyle

Comment: How could that help?
As far as I know, `drawComplexControl()` is virtual in `QStyle` and the class inheritance is as follows:

`QStyleSheetStyle` ---> `QWindowsStyle` ---> `QCommonStyle` --> `QStyle`.

Moreover, I tried to include `QStyleSheetStyle.h` in my code but I got many linker errors which I wasn't able to fix.