# QCheckBox indicator size is wrong after stylesheet was applied

Tags: qt, qt4.6, qtstylesheets, qstyle

I created an own checkbox class from `QCheckBox` class. In my implementation I   use size of checkbox indicator and checkbox label spacing for my internal algorithms.

I get sizes like this:

```
// Checkbox indicator size.
style()->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_CheckBoxIndicator, &option);

// Checkbox label spacing size.
style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_CheckBoxLabelSpacing, &option);
```

For standard widget it works OK. But when I apply qss on my widget with custom indicator icon with another size,  I still get standard values, instead of qss one.

How can I get a correct values for styled widget? **I am using Qt 4.6.**

Comment: not enough code. What are you tying to achieve/change? Why style sheet is not enough?

Comment: Don't use QSS. Because `QStyle` does not support a lot of features of QSS. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138100/how-to-draw-control-with-qstyle-and-with-specified-qss